# Maximum setlocal recursion level reached. Can't print more then 30 times?

Tags: command-line, passwords, printing, batch-file

I want to print a defined number of passwords to a file. The code I found on this site is made for 30 loops as I see and I want to print much more, say, 1000. After a few runs, I get this, error? "Maximum setlocal recursion level reached." How can I fix it?

```
@echo off
set execute counter=0
:loop
(@Echo off  
rem 16 stings pwd

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)

echo pwd=%pwd% >> D:\password.txt

)
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="1000" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "Maximum setlocal recursion level reached." How can I fix it?

Move the `setlocal` and `set` commands before the loop. You don't need to execute these multiple times.

Other things that should be fixed:

- `echo pwd=%pwd% >> D:\password.txt` needs to be moved (otherwise the first line of the file will be `password=` with no value
- Add `setlocal` (with no arguments) as well at the beginning (otherwise your variables are set in the enclosing cmd shell)
- Add a matching `endlocal` at the end of the file
- See explanation below regarding use of `setlocal`/`endlocal`
- You have a space in `set execute counter=0` which shouldn't be there
- `rnd_num` needs to be between `0` and `61` **not** `0` and `62` (otherwise `ECHO` is inserted into the password when `rnd_num` is`62`

Here is the fixed batch file:

```
@echo off
set executecounter=0
setlocal
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

:loop
(@Echo off  
rem 16 stings pwd

set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)


)
echo pwd=%pwd% >> D:\password.txt
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="1000" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
endlocal
pause
```

---

> SETLOCAL on it's own, usually at the start of a batch file, will begin
>   localisation of Environment Variables.
>
> Issuing a SETLOCAL command, the batch script will inherit all current
>   variables from the master environment/session.
>
> Issuing an ENDLOCAL command will restore any environment variables
>   present before the SETLOCAL was issued.
>
> If a batch script does not use SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL then all
>   variables will be Global, i.e. visible and modifiable by other
>   scripts.
>
> Although global variables are easy to work with they are not good
>   practice - for example if you have several batch scripts dealing with
>   filenames (and these scripts are CALLing one another), the first
>   script has a variable called _filename, the second script a different
>   variable called file-name (a different name to avoid conflicting with
>   the first script) a third script now needs something like file_name
>   this quickly becomes very difficult to manage.
>
> With local variables you are free to use the same variable names in
>   multiple batch scripts - there is no conflict because the local
>   variables are not visible to any other script.
>
> Local Variables can be passed from one batch routine to another with
>   the ENDLOCAL command.

Source [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

Comment: I think the setlocal thing was put like that for a reason. The script just broke and it dosen't respect the generation parameters.

This is how it should generate the passwords:
pwd=6k4BjpSkCjFhuSOta 
pwd=zmjUzgpgwD3gQnylC 
 And this is what it does now: pwd=oHxgUX7HN2lSLXeyH 
pwd=oHxgUX7HN2lSLXeyHHrjdsC0vTex93tH1M 
pwd=oHxgUX7HN2lSLXeyHHrjdsC0vTex93tH1MKI0ZP5nJj7VgwFEPN 
pwd=oHxgUX7HN2lSLXeyHHrjdsC0vTex93tH1MKI0ZP5nJj7VgwFEPNywaE8dzVEgVnwBvMR 
pwd=oHxgUX7HN2lSLXeyHHrjdsC0vTex93tH1MKI0ZP5nJj7VgwFEPNywaE8dzVEgVnwBvMRJB8xZYWDp3GBx6SiECHO. It goes on adding to the first one generated...

Comment: @Unix Apologies, my mistake `set pwd=` needs to be in the loop. There is another (different) error though. Answer corrected.

Comment: @Unix Please try the updated script from my answer.

Comment: It looks like its running perfect, it went past 60 passwords. And I also noticed that after each password I also have a space [_]. Is there a bug in the code or is something the cmd does?

Comment: Ah, It is `echo` doing that. Replacing `echo pwd=%pwd% >> D:\password.txt` with `echo pwd=%pwd%>> D:\password.txt`

Comment: There is another problem I noticed which I haven't been able to fix - every so often there is `ECHO` in the middle of a password, eg `pwd=HVc6GH1DWxECHOmPwrjF`. I noticed it when I was looking at your previous question. I've no idea why :(

Comment: Haven't seen that. It's useless then. I have another generator code but it's too big to post here. Can the chat be used for this? :/

Comment: Found it. It happens only when `rnd_num=62`. Remove the `+1` from the end of the `rnd_num` calculation > `SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768`. Answer updated ;)

Comment: @Unix Random needs to be between 0 and 61 not 0 and 62

Comment: Done. But I also noticed that it actually generates a 17 chr password instead of 16. Should I make some modifications on this line? `FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (` if I change it with 32 will it generate longer passwords?
EDIT!: If I modify that it starts to generate only 1 chr/line pwd=a,pwd=b, etc.

Comment: @Unix Yes, change to 15 for 16 length passwords. It will generate passwords as big as you like (I would try for too many though, it wil take too long). I have it working for (0, 1, 100) which is 101 characters.

Comment: I only need it to generate 32 alphanumeric and special characters for WiFi pentest wordlist. It finally works perfect though I have another code that I think I'll open another question for it cause it's to big to comment here :)) thanks for the help with this one

Comment: @Unix No problem. I will look out for your next question ;)